# Grouping hive rows in an array of this rows

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table like the following :

```
User:String Alias:String
JohnDoe     John
JohnDoe     JDoe
Roger       Roger
```

And I would like to group all the aliases of an user in an array, in a new table which would look like this :

```
User:String Alias:array<String>
JohnDoe     [John, JDoe]
Roger       [Roger]
```

I can't figure out how to do that with HiveQL.Do I have to write an UDF for that ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check out the [built-in aggregate function](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-udf.html#LanguageManualUDF-BuiltinAggregateFunctions%2528UDAF%2529) `collect_set`.

```
select 
    User, 
    collect_set(Alias) as Alias
from table
group by User;
```

Comment: is there any way to use collect_set for struct type field.