# Hive - grouping rows into map

Tags: dictionary, hive, grouping

I have a table like so

```
Col1   Col2   Col3
A      1      word1
A      2      word2
A      3      word3
A      4      word4
B      1      word1
B      3      word3
```

And I want to group col2 and col3 by col1, but keep col2 and col3 in a map, like so:

```
Col1   map(col2, col3)
A      [(1, word1), (2, word2), (3, word3), (4, word4)]
B      [(1, word1), (3, word3)]
```

I know there is a way to do this with just an array, as appears here: [Grouping hive rows in an array of this rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836702/grouping-hive-rows-in-an-array-of-this-rows)

But I'm wondering if this is possible with a map (key/value pairs).

Answer (score 3):

Use the "collect" UDF in BrickHouse http://github.com/klout/brickhouse

```
select col1, collect( col2, col3 )
from mytable
group by col1
```

You can also merge maps with the "union_map" UDAF

Comment: It's not liking something about the grouping.... `hive> create table t1 as select A, collect(B, C) FROM t2 group by A;
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 1:35 Expression not in GROUP BY key 'C'` And I've also tried it with `group by A, C` and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Make sure the BrickHouse jars are in your HIVE_AUX_JARS, and that you've defined the brickhouse UDF's by sourcing brickhouse.hql. IE...
    CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION collect AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.CollectUDAF';` did the trick