# Hive aggregation (union) function that takes a map with json value

Tags: json, hive, union, brickhouse

I have the table:

```
id, name, value
1, 'A', "{"key_a": 1, "key_b": 2}"
1, 'B', "{"key_a": 2, "key_b": 2}"
1, 'C', "{"key_a": 2, "key_b": 3}"
```

and I need aggregate those data to id:

```
id, json
1, "{'A': {"key_a": 1, "key_b": 2}, 'B': {"key_a": 2, "key_b": 2}, 'C': {"key_a": 2, "key_b": 3}}
```

I tried to use bh_union function but it doesn't work.
Is there any other option than to write a python reduce script?

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION bh_union AS 'brickhouse.udf.collect.UnionUDAF'; 

SELECT id, bh_union(map(name, value)) json
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id, 
        name, 
        to_json(map('A', SUM(`count`), 'B', COUNT(`count`))) value
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY id, name
) a
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the "collect" UDF in BrickHouse http://github.com/klout/brickhouse

For refernece you can look at answer to this [Hive - grouping rows into map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409543/hive-grouping-rows-into-map)