# create nested data from from un-nested data in hive

Tags: arrays, hadoop, hive, hiveql, parquet

Is there any way that I can create nested data in hive from un-nested data

Example:
source table

```
id zip_code
123 12345
123 23456
123 56789
234 12345
234 99999
```

to look like this

```
id zipcode
123 12345,23456,56789
234 12345,99999
```

Do note that the number of zipcode's for an id can be varying

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouping hive rows in an array of this rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836702/grouping-hive-rows-in-an-array-of-this-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id
     , concat_ws(',',collect_set(zip_code)) as zipcode 
  from your_table 
 group by id
```

collect_set() will remove duplicates in zip_code collection. If you need duplicates, use collect_list instead